# object value is undefined in angular js

Tags: php, angularjs

i first populate my form with result retrieved from database using PHP and initialize the values to the form using `ng-init`.

So I get the values in the object but I cannot seem to access single element of the object. Getting undefined.

i am trying to access my `$scope.object` values . I have name and address details stored in it, so I want for eg. `$scope.object.state_id` value and copy it into another variable.

i get the value as `undefined` but when I display it in the HTML page using `{{object}}`. It shows the data in the object.

i pass the $id as a URL parameter

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
$query="CALL sp_candidate_populate('$id')";
$response=mysqli_query($conn,$query);

while($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($response))
{


?>  
<form   name="myForm" novalidate>

<p ng-init="obj.cankey='<?php echo $id; ?>' " >

<label>FirstName:</label>
<input type="text" name="fn" ng-model="obj.fn" ng-init="obj.fn='<?php echo $r['elect_candidate_fname']; ?>' " required>
```

```
<p><label>State:</label>
<select name="state1" ng-model="obj.state1" ng-init="obj.state1='<?php echo $r['gen_state_key']; ?>'">

        <option ng-repeat="x in catt" value="{{x.gen_state_key}}">{{x.gen_state_name}}</option>
    </select>
        </p>

<p>
<input type="button"  ng-click="updateform()"  name="submit"alue="Update">

</p>
</form>

{{obj}}


</div>


<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('validateCtrl', function($scope, $http,$log) {
$scope.address = {};
```

getting the state id to compare and show in the drop down list .

```
$http.get("get_state.php").then(function(response) {
$scope.catt = response.data.records;  
}); 



$scope.obj = {};

$scope.updateform = function() {
$http({
      method  : 'POST',
      url     : 'add_update.php',
      data    : $scope.obj,
      headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlrncoded'} 
     })
      .success(function(data) {
          alert("Update Successful");

      });
      }

console.log($scope.obj);
});


</script>
```

While posting the data using $http service i get the object values and update takes place . But when trying to access the values one element at a time i get undefined

Comment: Try doing an console.log() on the object and see if you have an actual javascript object or just a string in json format.

Comment: It is returning Object {  }  . So my object is empty but how come it is showing that the object filled with data on the html while doing this {{object}}

Comment: Update your question with the parts of your code relevant to the problem.

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Made changes to the post now

Comment: Start of the code is a php script where in i get the details of that id and assign it in the form using ng-init